# What does macromodel mean in this context?

Tags: integrated-circuit, model

I was looking for the meaning of IC "macromodel". And I came across the following:

[image]

They call the above schematics of the opmap IC as its "macromodel".

But what is modelled here? They show all the components explicitly with all nodes.

I thought I would find something like a simplified diagram. Is the above schematics correctly called as macromodel? If not, what is an IC macromodel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'macromodel' is a SPICE representation of an IC or other complex block. It's a 'macro' as it's a collection of individual models connected together into a larger entity, in this case, an op-amp.

The schematic you show is a diagram of that SPICE macromodel.